# Nginx Cache: how to expire/vary by request date

Tags: caching, nginx, http-headers

I've got content that changes depending on the date it is requested on, i.e. 
the same content will be served when the page is requested at `2018-09-10T00:00` and `2018-09-10T23:59`, but different content will be served at `2018-09-11T00:00` (based on the server time).

Is there a `vary` http header I can set on the content that will achieve this (set by the upstream server)?

Or is there another way of doing this in nginx (ideally only on certain paths)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side caching is controlled by setting cache control headers.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires for a discussion of the options. It is possible to specify the time of day using the @ prefix. So your config would look something like this for setting expiry at 3:30 pm server time:

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
  expires @15h30m;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

If your content expired every hour, you could so something fancy like do a time calculation in lua and set that to an ngx variable which is used by expire.

Comment: Thank you, somehow missed the option of an absolute value for `expires`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "Expires" header, which you can do in Nginx or in your application. The header would look like this, just as an example:

```
Expires: Sun, 09 Oct 2016 23:59:59 GMT
```

In PHP you could generate this with:

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime(date("Y-m-d 23:59:59"))) . ' GMT');
```

In Nginx you just need to add the following to your location or server block which serves the specified content:

```
expires @00h00m;
```

That way the content would expire at midnight.